# Letter printing until the whole word is finally displayed in the form of a triangle, Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, math, cpu-word

[Output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Cr2.png)

Here is my code:

```
 public static String repeat(String s, int n) {
    String res = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res += s;

    }
    return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String word = "mathematics";
    int n = word.length()/2;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.print(repeat(" ", n- i));
        System.out.println(word.substring(n -1, n + i + 1)); //here is the problem I think

    }

}
```

Or do you know some better solution? Thanks

Comment: What output do you get from the code as written?

Comment: I get only left half without the first line @JimKiley

Comment: If you do not get what you need then ***any*** working solution is better than yours.  Internet in general and SO in particular are full of such programs.  Do a bit of research.

Comment: I suspect that your theory about the 'substring' line is correct. Notice that n never changes, so n-1 never changes, so the start point of your substring never changes.

Comment: You should also work on the formatting of your code, it is inconsistent and the variable names have no meanings. This should only be done when on a serious time crunch or when you do not want to use the program again. Maybe make a comment reminding yourself what repeat is supposed to do and why you need a function to do that?

Comment: @Sean I am a beginner in programming and it is difficult for me to use loops in loops right away, so I make the functions to make it easier for myself, but I will work on formatting, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The start index of your substring is `n-1` which is constant, but it has to change, it has to be `n-i` to decrease to the start of the word

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    System.out.print(repeat(" ", n- i));
    System.out.println(word.substring(n -i, n + i + 1)); 
}
```

---

```
     m
    ema
   hemat
  themati
 athematic
mathematics
```